# /templates/_helpers.tpl:14:27: executing "fullname" at <.Chart.Name>: can't evaluate field Chart in type string

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm getting the error in the helm when I run a Helm chart.  `helpers.tpl` contains:

```
{{- define "fullname" -}}

{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride -}}

{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: How are you calling this template?  (There should be a `{{ template "fullname" ??? }}` or `{{ include "fullname" ??? }}` call, and if the `???` is a string-typed expression and not the Helm root object, it would produce that error.)

Comment: @David Maze  I'm calling it in ingress yaml like                                                                              kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "fullname" . }}

Answer (score 1):

There was a format issue in my ingress.yml . Thanks